# Rails Engines: Make host app javascript available to Mounted Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, rails-engines

Here is a quick visual of what I am trying to do:

```
var hostAppJs = {
    callMe: function(){
        alert("CALL ME FROM MAIN APP ");
    }
}

var hookedInEngineJs = {
    init: function(){
        $('button').on('click', function(){
            hostAppJs.callMe();
        });         
    }
}
hookedInEngineJs.init();
```

Basically, I want all of the host app's javascript available to the mounted engine.  When the javascript is all tethered together for my mounted engine, it should look like it is above, even though the `hostAppJs` javascript object only exists within the host app, and the `hookedInEngineJs` javascript object only exists in the mounted engine.

The problem that I am running into is that when I am inside the mounted engine, it cannot find the `hostAppJs` object, so it appears that it is not being loaded in correctly for the mounted engine.

Here is my my `application.js` file for my host app:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And here is my `application.js` file for my mounted engine:

```
//= require '/<absolutePathToHostApp>/assets/javascripts/application.js'
//= require_tree .
```

So I am assuming that for my mounted engine, all the javascript from the host app gets loaded in and made available to my engine, and then it loads in all of its own javascript.  Thus, I would think that my host app's javascript is available for my engine.  Sadly, it isn't working.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: In each of your engines: if you want to load in the host app's javascript file, simple add this line in the engine's javascript manifest file:

```
//= require application.js
```

This refers to the host app's `application.js` file, NOT the engines.  The engine's application.js file is namespaced in order to distinguish between the two:

ex: `my_engine/application.js`

Same thing for loading in the host app's css into each of the engine's css.  Just put this line in the engine's manifest file to make the host app's css available to your engines:

```
*= require application.css
```